# How long should I slow roast a large (7.5lb/3.5kg) chicken for?

Tags: chicken, slow-cooking, roast

This [Moroccan Slow Roasted Chicken with Preserved Lemon and Olives
recipe](http://moroccanfood.about.com/od/maindishes/r/Roasted_Chicken.htm) suggests to cook a regular sized chicken for 3 hours at 325° F (160° C).

I have a largish chicken (7.5lb/3.5kg) that I want to cook. For how long should I (slow) roast this chicken for?

Answer (score 4):

That's the largest chicken I've ever heard of.

That said, 3 to 3.5 hours at 325℉ should be sufficient. Unfortunately time doesn't really matter when cooking chicken, but temperature. You should definitely be using a meat thermometer and cooking long enough for the breasts to reach 160℉ and the thighs 170℉.

If you don't have a thermometer the next best thing would be to poke the thigh when you think it's done and confirm that the juices run clear. If they are not clear, then it needs to be cooked longer.

Comment: that's not the largest on the market.  At least in the US, chickens (plucked and dressed for sale) between 2.5-4 lbs are called "fryers," between 4-6 lbs are "broilers," and 6-8 lbs are "roasters."  Though I don't see too many roasters in my local megamart, Purdue and Tysons, both industrial producers of chicken, sell all three types nationwide.  Larger chickens (stewing hens) are available in some local farmers' markets.

Comment: Grainfed chickens can get very large. I have one over 8lb.

Answer (score 1):

It will probably take more time than called for by the recipe, but not much. I would start checking at the three hour mark, then every 15-20 minutes until done.

Answer (score 0):

I used this roast calculator. It suggests 180C for the first 20 minutes (if you have a gas stove.) And then 160C for 2 hours 20 minutes after that. [roast timer BBC](http://www.bbcgoodfood.com/howto/tools/roast-timer)

Answer (score 0):

Because of the large amount of breast meat, you'll need to cook the capon at 400°F for the first 30 mins (oven preheated) then reduce to 350/325 for the last 2 hours.

Comment: Hi! Your terminology correction may be correct, but it is not too relevant for people who wanted to know the cooking time. I replaced that by the content of your comment, which actually addressed what the OP asked for.